# Importing html file to edit like csv file

Tags: python, html, pandas

I was just trying to read html file that I got from fm2019(player stats) to python so that I can play(practice) my python skills with them.

However, it seems that when I read the html file ([html file](http://localhost:8889/view/Documents/data%20science/physical.html)) by

```
> df = pd.read_html('file.html')
```

it returns it to me just as a list, as if the whole thing is in just one cell in a table. There are no headers and I can't edit the data.

How can I import this html file as a data frame as if its a csv file?

I am working on Jupyter notebook(anaconda).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get list of DataFrames, so need select e.g. first Dataframe by `[0]`:

```
df = pd.read_html('file.html')[0]
```